# What is wrong whith my sql command?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've tried this for several hours but I cannot figure it our what's wrong

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = 
    "select Calle.Id_Calle FROM" + 
      "TominPredial.Calle as Calle,"+
      "TominPredial.Colonia as Col," +
      "TominPredial.Poblacion as Pob" +
     "WHERE Calle.Nombre = @NombreCalle" +
            "and Col.Id_Colonia = @id_col and Pob.Id_Poblacion = @id_pob";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NombreCalle", nombreCalle);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_col", id_col);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id_pob", id_pob);
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

It says incorrect syntax near "Calle"

Comment: you are selecting one field from 3 tables. Why aren't you joining the tables?

Comment: @polin I don't need to join them, I just need the Id, this is why I use ExecuteScalar

Comment: That's an implicit inner join.

Comment: Adding a space at the end of each of your substrings will help.

Comment: Consider using a multiline string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no space between the lines:

```
"select Calle.Id_Calle FROM" + 
  "TominPredial.Calle as Calle,"+
  "TominPredial.Colonia as Col," +
  "TominPredial.Poblacion as Pob" +
 "WHERE Calle.Nombre = @NombreCalle" +
        "and Col.Id_Colonia = @id_col and Pob.Id_Poblacion = @id_pob";
```

This will make the query `... FROMTominpredial.calle ... pobWHERE ..` which will generate a syntax error.

You have to put spaces between the keywords in the end of the lines. Something like so:

```
...
"select Calle.Id_Calle FROM" + 
" TominPredial.Calle as Calle,"+
" TominPredial.Colonia as Col," +
" TominPredial.Poblacion as Pob" +
" WHERE Calle.Nombre = @NombreCalle" +
"   and Col.Id_Colonia = @id_col and Pob.Id_Poblacion = @id_pob"; 
/\
put a Spaces here
```

Comment: This error is in two more places. Just debug it and see the text's value without newlines and see where you forgot a space.